# Is it possible to share applications between the host machine and guest machine using Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to setup host machine browser as default guest system browser](https://superuser.com/questions/473140/is-it-possible-to-setup-host-machine-browser-as-default-guest-system-browser)

I'm running Virtualbox with a Windows 7 host machine and Ubuntu guest machine, and I'd like to use Google Chrome (on Windows) as the default browser in the guest machine. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @Gareth I think this question should not have been closed; it addresses launching host applications from the guest system as well as launching guest applications from the host system.

Comment: I believe it is still a duplicate; both are asking how to launch an applications on the Host from within the Guest