# can I control host applications from a VirtualBox guest?

Tags: virtualbox

I have a feeling this is impossible, but I can't find a definitive answer searching around.

Here's what I'd like to do. Ssh'ing from within Chrome (on Windows) into a Debian guest, have a command within the guest launch a tab in Chrome with a URL supplied by the guest command.

More specifically, I'm using newsbeuter, running in a Debian guest, in a ssh session in Chrome (on the host). Instead of opening articles in the guest, I'd like to open the articles in my host Chrome.

**edit**:

Here is a similar question, [Is it possible to setup host machine browser as default guest system browser](https://superuser.com/questions/473140/is-it-possible-to-setup-host-machine-browser-as-default-guest-system-browser) .

The only answer seems to be to use ssh to send commands from guest to host. Are there other options?

Comment: Do you want your guest OS (Debian) opening a tab on your Chrome browser on your host (Windows)? If yes, then there is no exact solutions to that.

Comment: yes @Huygens, that's what I want.