# Open Host applications from VMWare guest

Tags: gnome, vmware-player, vmware-tools

I have a Windows 7 host and a Linux (CentOS) guest VMWare installation. I often use `gnome-open` in the guest to open a URL in the default browser. Is there a way to open the host’s browser instead?

Ideally, gnome-open would always open the host’s browser but I could live with a solution where I’d have to use a custom command.

I know there’s a similar question [already](https://superuser.com/questions/473140/is-it-possible-to-setup-host-machine-browser-as-default-guest-system-browser) but it isn’t specific to VMWare. And I know that WVMWare Fusion on OSX lets me specify the guest’s default browser to be an app of the host (and vice-versa):

[image: VMWare Fusion settings]

Maybe the same is available on other VMWare products?

I have VMWare Player 6.0.3 and vmware-tools are installed on the guest.