# Is it possible to host a Virtual Image server that is accessible to the host computer?

Tags: ubuntu

I have a Ubuntu Virtual Image on my VirtualBox program. For testing purposes in the office, I would like the employees to be able to access this Virtual Image server that is hosted on my computer. Is this possibe?

I found this thread, but it is for the reverse action: [VirtualBox guest OS accessing local server on host OS](https://superuser.com/questions/144453/virtualbox-guest-os-accessing-local-server-on-host-os)

Comment: The first question is how do you access that virtual machine? E.g. if you do a tracert (not sure what is your main OS) what hops does it take to get to the virtual image? Your going to be looking at adding a static DNS entry if they need to access it by a hostname and some routing as well...

Comment: If you mean. Each user would be able to run their own instance of that virtual machine, then that might be possible, but not with VirtualBox alone.  Please clarify your question.